# Vue.js computed value returning undefined

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I have been having trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong with this code.

```
    name: 'StatementInfo',
    data() {
        return {
            currentStatement: {
                client: '',
                clientEmail: '',
                date: '',
                hours: '',
                hourlyRate: '',
                total: this.calcTotal
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        calcTotal () {
            return parseInt(this.hours) * parseInt(this.hourlyRate)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        saveForm () {
            console.log(this.currentStatement)
            this.$emit('save-form', this.currentStatement)
        },
  }
```

Console logging this.currentStatement causes total to be undefined, but from a junior devs perspective, I would have imagined this to work. Can any more experienced people take a gander at this and tell me what it could be?

Comment: Can you create a small demo for this using any online code editor like codesandbox, etc. Then others can debug the issue better and provide some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how reactivity works in relation to `computed methods`.

The content of `data` is evaluated once and at that point `this.calcTotal` is undefined. That value will remain like that until you update it.

You should directly use your computed method when you need it.

So use `calcTotal` instead of `total`.

Comment: Do you meant that I should just change ```total``` in currentStatement to ```calcTotal``` or where should I use ```calcTotal``` instead of ```total```

Comment: You should use calcTotal instead of total

Comment: this did not seem to work, it either return NaN or undefined, can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: That's possible as you're not making sure that hours and hourly rate are integers. With your default values you'll get NaN.

Comment: For that reason I have put the ```parseInt```. Could it be that I am executing that incorrectly?

Comment: parseInt will return NaN if the parsed value cannot be parsed. the result for parseInt('') is NaN. You probably need to check the result and if NaN then assign a default value.

Comment: It seems like no matter what I do it always returns NaN, either that or undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign default values to this.hours and this.hourlyRate = 0,
maybe when you execute saveForm(), that variables are null or undefined

Comment: The problem with that is the fields that those are linked to need thier placeholder tet to stay intact on the page loading. After trying this suggestion it still returned undefined.